# Word 2013 Textbox Clipping

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

When I insert a textbox into a Word document the content is clipped on the left side, like this:
[image]

Some of the text isn't visible it doesn't help to make it bigger. Have any of you experienced anything similar. It stays the same if I replace the text with some of my own.

Do you now how to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've successfully duplicated your symptoms on Office for Mac (it's an Office problem, not a Windows problem):

[image]

See the rulers at the top? Notice that the small rectangle below the rulers (the block thingy below the hourglass-like arrows) is to the **left** of the left edge of the text box. This basically means that the text will start off of the screen, outside of the text box.

How do we fix it? Let's move the boundary back into the text box. I'll drag the rectangle to the right until the left margin is within the box again (don't drag the hourglass arrows; those control the newline and line break points, which you can move all at once with the rectangle). If you can't see the rulers, go the **View** tab in the Ribbon and click **Show Rulers** or something like that. Once I finish dragging the rectangle marker back into the correct place, the text appears normal again:

[image]

Well would you look at that! The text is back in the box, right where it should be.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that if I start with pressing backspace with my cursor infront of the text it also jumps into place.
But your answer is obviously the right solution. Thanks again!